# How to add images to existing item with ebay API

Tags: python, image, upload, ebay-api

I am using ebay-sdk for python. I uploaded some images to eBay Picture Services(EPS) successfully using the below code:

```
from ebaysdk.trading import Connection as Trading

api = Trading(config_file='ebay.yaml', siteid=71)


def upload_images(image_url):
    response = api.execute('UploadSiteHostedPictures', {"ExternalPictureURL": image_url,
                                                             "PictureSet": "Supersize"})
    return response.content

upload_images(MY_IMG_URL)
```

eBay returns the URL of the uploaded images.

But how can I add the images to my existing eBay offers? Do I have to use ReviseItem?

An example using the ebay-sdk for python would be nice.

Edit:

```
    def revise_image(self, item_id):
    myitem = {
        "Item": {
            "Country": "DE",
            "ItemID": item_id,
            "PictureDetails": [
                {"PictureURL": MY_IMG1},
                {"PictureURL": MY_IMG2},
                {"PictureURL": MY_IMG3}
            ]
        }
    }
    response = self.api.execute('ReviseFixedPriceItem', myitem)
```

I made the changes as suggested but it still only changes the main image. MY_IMG3 becomes the main image. MY_IMG1 and MY_IMG2 are not appended to the listing.

Answer (score 0):

This works.

```
def verifyAddItem(args):
        #"""http://www.utilities-online.info/xmltojson/#.UXli2it4avc   """
    try:
        api = Trading(debug=args.debug, siteid=site_id, appid=app_id, token=token_id, config_file=None, certid=cert_id, devid=dev_id)

        myitem = {
            "Item": {
                "Country": "GB",
                "Description": description,
                "ItemID": item_to_revise,
                "PictureDetails": {
                    "PictureURL": "http://www.itcircleconsult.com/eb2017/4a.png"
                    },
                }
            }

        api.execute('ReviseFixedPriceItem', myitem)
        dump(api)
```

I have been working a lot with eBay and Python..

Check here for some working examples.. I often rip them apart and put them back together on the fly but you might find some use..

There is an I-ways checker and some BS4 ripping to revise items as well

https://github.com/johnashu/PRODUCTION/tree/master/Python/eBay%20API%20KIT%20-%20Maffas%20-%202017

another useful thing is check out the eBay API call index here:

http://developer.ebay.com/devzone/xml/docs/Reference/eBay/index.html#CallIndex

then use an XML to JSON convertor to change the calls you need into a more readable format in pythong..

Here:

http://www.utilities-online.info/xmltojson/#.WTW_P8b-vct

NOTES ON ADDING IMAGES AND HOSTING:

https://developer.ebay.com/devzone/xml/docs/reference/ebay/UploadSiteHostedPictures.html

Note: As of release 889, you do not need to use this call to upload self-hosted images before creating the listing. You can now specify up to 12 self-hosted or EPS hosted URLs at once in Item.PictureDetails.PictureURL using the AddItem or AddFixedPriceItem calls. However, you must use the UploadSiteHostedPictures call to upload binary attachments.

The supposed JSON needed it this.. unless it takes time to populate the pictures to the item?

We were both Missing  [] - Schoolboy error!

```
{
"Item": {
    "PictureDetails": [
    { "PictureURL": "http://pics.ebay.com/aw/pics/dot_clear.gif" },
    { "PictureURL": "fds" },
    { "PictureURL": "fds" }
    ]
}
}
```

Comment: You can change ReviseListedItem to ReviseItem or whatever call you wish to make.. 

just to note i Use python 3.6

Comment: Thanks a lot. With your example I can change the main image. But I want to add images to the item, not change the main image. How can that be done?

Comment: Sorry i forgot to mention.. 
To specify multiple pictures, send each URL in a separate, PictureDetails.PictureURL element. The first URL passed in will be the Gallery image and appears on the View Item page.

Comment: I have edited my main post for some code. Please tell me what I did wrong.

Comment: Hi i have updated my answer and added hosting notes at the bottom.. the code should be correct..

Comment: ive changed it again as apparently you can upload them all.. I really need the answer to this as well now!!

Comment: I edited the code yesterday as to your suggestion. But it still does not work.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is quite old, but I stumbled across this page because I ran into the same problem and found the correct solution.

As mentioned in the comments above, the currently posted solution by johnashu does not work. This is because of the way **ebaysdk.utils.dict2xml** converts dictionaries.

The above solution of:

```
{
"Item": {
    "PictureDetails": [
    { "PictureURL": "http://pics.ebay.com/aw/pics/dot_clear.gif" },
    { "PictureURL": "fds" },
    { "PictureURL": "fds" }
    ]
}
}
```

Outputs XML of:

```
<Item>
  <PictureDetails>
    <PictureURL>http://pics.ebay.com/aw/pics/dot_clear.gif</PictureURL>
  </PictureDetails>
  <PictureDetails>
    <PictureURL>fds</PictureURL>
  </PictureDetails>
  <PictureDetails>
    <PictureURL>fds</PictureURL>
  </PictureDetails>
</Item>
```

Which includes multiple `<PictureDetails>` rather than one parent tag, with multiple `PictureURL` tags as children.

**The correct format is:**

```
{
  "Item": {
    "PictureDetails": {
      'PictureURL': ['http://pics.ebay.com/aw/pics/dot_clear.gif', 'fds', 'fds']
    }
  }
}
```

Which gives us an XML output of:

```
<Item>
  <PictureDetails>
    <PictureURL>http://pics.ebay.com/aw/pics/dot_clear.gif</PictureURL>
    <PictureURL>fds</PictureURL>
    <PictureURL>fds</PictureURL>
  </PictureDetails>
</Item>
```

Which matches the format described in the [ReviseItem API docs](https://developer.ebay.com/devzone/xml/docs/reference/ebay/ReviseItem.html).